# C preproc: pasting valid token and value of a token

Tags: c, token, c-preprocessor, stm32, pasting

I am working with an STM32F1 microcontroller, for which a header is provided that defines bit masks and values for registers as follows:

```
#define RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL    //Mask of PLL multiplier setting bits
#define RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL1   //Value of PLL multiplier bits for PLL x1
#define RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL2   //Value of PLL multiplier bits for PLL x2
#define RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL3   //Value of PLL multiplier bits for PLL x3
```

etc etc.

What I want to do is define my PLL multiplier as an integer so I can use it to derive the clock value - ie `PLLCLK = IN_CLK * PLL_MULT` - and paste the value onto `RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL` to obtain the correct setting bits. The macros I would normally use for this are as follows:

```
#define APPEND_VAL_HELPER(A, B)   A##B
#define APPEND_VAL(A, B)          APPEND_VAL_HELPER(A,B)
```

Then if I define SOME_NUM as, say, 123:

```
#define FOO                       APPEND_VAL(BAR, SOME_NUM)
```

Results in the `FOO` defining as `BAR123`. Normally this works. Here's the problem: in this case, `RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL` is a valid token before being pasted. This results in it expanding in the invocation of `APPEND_VAL` and I get something like `((uint32_t)0x003C0000)123`. I can't figure out how to get `B` to expand without also expanding `A`, at least in GCC. There are workarounds to this but I'm looking for a clean solution. Does it exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you would consider a "clean" solution, but this works for me and doesn't seem too bad:

```
/* target header */
#define RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL         0x003C
#define RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL1        0x0003

/* pasting macros */
#define APPEND_VAL_HELPER(A, B)  A ## B
#define APPEND_VAL(A, B)         APPEND_VAL_HELPER(A, B)
#define RCC_CFGR(T, N)           APPEND_VAL(RCC_CFGR_, APPEND_VAL(T, N))
```

You use that as, for example,

```
#define FOO RCC_CFGR(PLLMUL, 1)
```

You can also do

```
#define BAR RCC_CFGR(PLLMUL, )
```

to define `BAR` to `RCC_CFGR_PLLMUL` (no tail).

Obviously, this is specific to a subset of possible target macros, but it does the job and reads cleanly.  To the best of my knowledge there is no way to write a fully general token-pasting macro -- those that are most general suffer from issues such as the one you described.

Comment: It's a lot better than the pile of #ifs I was envisioning or trying to kludge around the token by feeding the macro RCC_CFGR ## PLLMULL etc.

Comment: I ended up doing it a little different, but along the same lines:

`#define RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL_HELPER(A)  RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL ## A
#define RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL_GEN(A)     RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL_HELPER(A)
#define PLLMULL_BITS                RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL_GEN(FOO)`
    
It requires a set of macros for each generated value, but keeps all the information in one place.