# How to use value of a symbolic constant in token-pasting operator?

Tags: c, gcc

My code looks something like this:

```
#define LIMB_SIZE 8
...
#define DATA_TYPE uint ## LIMB_SIZE ## _t
...
DATATYPE a;
...
```

Corresponding pre-processed output looks like this:

```
uintLIMBSIZE_t a;
```

while I was expecting

```
uint8_t a;
```

- Is it the expected behavior? (It works the same way even if spaces across token-pasting operator are removed)
- If yes, what's the alternative so that, I can use define `LIMB_SIZE` from command-line? (Assume `LIMB_SIZE` will be one among 8, 16, 32)
- If no, what am I missing?

I used `gcc -E file.c` to verify the pre-processed output

Comment: This is surely a duplicate.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491991/c-preproc-pasting-valid-token-and-value-of-a-token has an answer, but I think there is a more canonical question on this which I can't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processing of an object-like macro is largely:

1. Replace the macro with its replacement tokens.
2. Apply `#` and `##` operators.
3. Process macros in the new tokens.

So, by the time processing gets to replacing the `LIMB_SIZE` in the replacement list, it is at step 3. However, step 2 already converted it to `uintLIMB_SIZE_t`, so the separate macro name is no longer present.

Function-like macros add another step:

0. For each parameter that appears in the replacement list not preceded by `#` or adjacent to `##`, replace the parameter with the result of replacing macros in the corresponding argument. If the parameter is preceded by `#`, it is replaced by the “stringized” argument. If the parameter is adjacent to `##`, it is replaced by the argument without replacing macros in it.

This means, to have `LIMB_SIZE` be expanded before `##` is processed, you need:

- It to appear in an argument of a function-like macro.
- The corresponding parameter of that macro not to be adjacent to `##`.

That requires using two function-like macros, so you can do this:

```
#define LIMB_SIZE 8

#define Helper0(x)  uint ## x ## _t   // Concatenate x.
#define Helper1(x)  Helper0(x)        // Replace macros in x.

#define DATA_TYPE Helper1(LIMB_SIZE)

DATA_TYPE a;
```

Comment: So, it's bit like having function like macros will resolve symbols before pre-processing other stuff